# How to find duplicate records from Sql from multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find rows from my MySql table, which contains same values on two columns.

My table is like

```
ID   NAME   EMAIL         Status
1    John   asd@asd.com   True
1    Sam    a@gmail.com   False
2    Tom    b@gmail.com   True
2    Bob    bob@asd.com   true
3    Jam    8@gmail.com   False
3    Mam    7@gmail.com   False
5    Tom    a23@asd.com   True
```

So, i want data from above table, with same id and status if its duplicates or else it should give me data with single id, and status = true. 
Result should be like:

```
ID   NAME   EMAIL         Status 
2    Tom    b@gmail.com   True
2    Bob    bob@asd.com   true
5    Tom    a23@asd.com   True
```

It means, i only need those rows with status = true and same id.

Comment: What if two equal false rows? Or one false and one true? Adjust your sample table data to include those combinations!

Comment: i dont need a two false one. i only need a row with true status and if there is more then duplicate ids then it must be true for both.

Comment: Still add those combinations to the sample data, to make things clearer!

Comment: okay i have added those combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by` with `having` clause as below

```
select *
  from tab
 where id in
 (
  select id
    from tab
   group by id
  having max(status)=min(status)
 ) 
   and status!='false'
```

[*Rextester Demo*](https://rextester.com/WVDS7507)

Comment: Just curious, how did you interpret this part of the OP's question "*or else it should give me data with single id, and status = true*" .. because it really sounds like they **also** want rows that are not duplicates but given a different treatment.  It's all a bit confusing.

Comment: @billynoah I considered he wants to have rows with `grouping by id, status` gives single results as long as status column doesn't equal to `false` in any case.

Comment: @Ozhan, yes, i wants rows with status true only. and if there is duplicate ids then status must be true for the id.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.status = 'false');
```

Answer (score 0):

Too late at the gravelpit, so this is just for old times sake.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS BEDROCK;
CREATE TABLE BEDROCK (ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(100), EMAIL VARCHAR(100), `Status` VARCHAR(6));

INSERT INTO BEDROCK (ID, NAME, EMAIL, `Status`) VALUES
(1,'Fred','fred.flintstone@stone.age','True'),
(1,'Wilma','wilma.flintstone@stone.age','False'),
(2,'Barney','barney.rubble@stone.age','True'),
(2,'Betty','betty.rubble@stone.age','True'),
(3,'Pebbles','pebbles.flintstone@stone.age','False'),
(3,'Bamm-Bamm','bamm-bamm.rubble@stone.age','False'),
(5,'Dino','dino@stone.age','True');

SELECT *
FROM BEDROCK t1
WHERE `Status` = 'true'
AND NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM BEDROCK t2
  WHERE t2.`Status` = 'false'
    AND t2.ID = t1.ID
);
```

**Result:**

```
ID  NAME    EMAIL                   Status
--  ------  ----------------------- ------
2   Barney  barney.rubble@stone.age True
2   Betty   betty.rubble@stone.age  True
5   Dino    dino@stone.age          True
```